# Pressing F8 on startup doesn’t show safe mode option nor restore - Win7

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, restore, safe-mode

After some power failures, my Windows 7 doesn’t display the common options to enter on safe mode, or restore at startup when I press <kbd>F8</kbd>. It shows only: Windows 7 and at the bottom of the screen, the utilitary to test memory.

Inside Windows, on control panel, I noticed that on the restore tab, when I click to activate restore, it doesn’t do anything. When I try to restore to an anterior point, an odd message appears. Looks like some part of windows is missing or got corrupted. The question is: How can I fix it without having to format and install everything again?

Answer (score 0):

Insert Windows 7 Installation DVD/USB 
boot the DVD/USB then click repair
After Successfully repair Now You can access <kbd>f8</kbd>

Comment: Hello, @shaagul shaaa , I already tried that. When trying to recover the windows through the DVD, it gives an error, saying that it can´t recover, and consult microsoft.

Comment: Go BIOS click load default settings   then F10 save & exit or u can try with bootable pendrive